# Font awesome icon has grey background only on mobile / iphone

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm having trouble figuring out why this font awesome 5 - Fa-cogs icon is coming up the way it is only on Iphone / mobile.
The icon has color: white assigned to it with a transparent background associated with the "A" tag
Screenshot - [[Icon Grey background]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUFtd.png)

Screenshot 2 - [filled background but there's still a border around it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dISz.png)

Comment: Would you be able to link the full element? Also are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "link the full element"? 
I am using bootstrap 3 alpha I believe.

Comment: from the consol, right click on the element > copy > copy element. But as you're using bootstrap and looking at the visual i'm pretty sure you're using a dropdown button with the a tag, so there is some kind of default css being applied. Would you be able to link the website? would be way more easier for me to fix your issue